# Why are there 2 different comment flag rate limitings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, comment-flags, rate-limiting

When I flag a comment, I get two different limits:

[image: You may only attempt to flag this comment every 3 seconds]

and

[image: You may only flag a comment every 5 seconds]

The first one was triggered by me trying to flag two comments on the same post that were obsolete - it popped up when I clicked the flag button (i.e. it is preventing me from opening the dialogue twice in 3 seconds):

[image: screenshot of an activated comment flag]

The second was encountered for the same reasons, but when I clicked "Flag comment" (i.e. it isn't letting me actually flag more than once every 5 seconds):

[image: screenshot of the comment flagging dialog]

Why are there two different rate limits for the same thing (flagging two comments)?

Even if they are to be kept (I think the 3 second one should go) I think they should be reworded to this:

> You may only try to flag comments once every 3 seconds

and

> You may only flag a comment once every 5 seconds

Comment: Despite having flagged a lot of comments, I have never seen the first one.

Comment: It has to be 2 comments that you flag, and you have to be quick

Comment: Try flagging my 2 comments

Comment: Does it really say obs**e**lete? o.o

Comment: @Raff nope, I just couldn't spell when I made the image! I make all the windows in Inkscape rather than screenshotting them because I get better quality etc...

Comment: There is something similar for close dialog: "you may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds". For the same reason, probably: this click hits deep enough into the system for it to be a DDOS vector. But I agree that *two* different limits look unnecessary: if the loading of dialog is already throttled, it should not be necessary  to throttle actual flagging.

Comment: @Raff it's possible to submit flags without any dialog so another layer of protection is vital.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah yes, the JS tricks. Then both should be set to the same duration, so that the normal clickety-click use of the site would never result in both pop-ups.

Comment: @Raff personally I prefer having it consistent with the [close dialog message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MZYZb.png): "You may only load the comment flag dialog every 3 seconds"

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358637/273494