# Wrong rate limit message when attempting to flag a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, flags, comment-flags

When clicking the flag link on a comment, I got the following message (emphasis mine):

> You may only attempt to flag **this comment** every 3 seconds.

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, that's incorrect; it was my first attempt at flagging this comment. It should be **a comment** instead, just like the rate limiting message for the flag itself:

> You may only flag a comment every 5 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be about loading the flag dialog, not about "attempt to flag"? While loading the flag dialog is part of attempting to flag, it's not actually the same thing.

Comment: Added to the devs' backlog to be addressed as part of regular bug duty rotation.

Answer (score 10):

I've made this fix. The new text will be:

> You may only load the comment flag dialog every #num# seconds.

Thanks for the suggestion in your answer, Ryan M; I think it makes a lot of sense to make them as parallel as possible. The fix should be in production today or tomorrow.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: You're welcome!  Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 9):

As Makyen [notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358637/wrong-rate-limit-message-when-attempting-to-flag-a-comment#comment1197455_358637), even that fix would still be somewhat inaccurate, because the limit is on opening the dialog, not attempting to flag.

It would be far better if it matched the rate limit error message for the normal flag dialog (perhaps, optionally, with "comment flag" substituted for "flag"):

> You may only load the flag dialog every 3 seconds.

This would match the rate limit message for the close dialog as well, bringing the rate limit messages for the three dialogs in line with each other.